# Code Challenge Solution With Logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I was doing some code challenges and I found this one:

[image]

And a guy submitted the following solution:

```
Int(ceil(log(window / h) / log(bounce))) * 2 - 1
```

`Int` means integer

`ceil` means round up

`log` means logarithm with base 10

Would you mind explaining this solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the parameter bounce $q$ and $h_k$ the height after $k$-th bounce. Since $h_{k + 1} = q h_k$, it follows that
$$h_k = q^kh_0 = q^k h.$$

Let $w$ be the height of the window. If $w \geq h$, the answer is $-1$ (I do not know, why $0$ is inappropriate). Otherwise,
the mother sees the ball at least once: when it passes the window after being dropped from the height $h$. After that, it sees it twice for each $k$, for which we have
$$h_k > w.$$
(Draw a sketch!)
Thus, we are looking for the maximal $k$ for which
$$ q^k h > w \Leftrightarrow q^k > w/h$$
still holds.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi Antoine, thank you for the answer. Can we explain me where hk=q kh0 comes from please? (sorry for silly question)

Comment: $h_0 = h = q^0  h$, $h_1 = q h_0 = q^1 h$, $h_2 = q h_1 = qqh_0 = q^2 h$, etc. You can also prove this by induction: for $k = 0$: beginning of this comment. $k\to k + 1$: $h_{k + 1} = q h_k$ (follows from the formulation of the problem). Induction hypothesis is that $h_k = q^k h$, hence $h_{k + 1} = qq^k h = q^{k + 1}h$.

Comment: I apologise for my stupid question. Thank you for your patience and have a good weekend.

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa The question was not stupid, don't worry.